# Native C code debugging in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-ndk, android-studio-2.2

Is it possible to debug android native c code in android studio 2.2 and above? I have gone through some blogs which has told to use experimental plugin for gradle. Is there a way to debug code in native c without using the experimental plugin in android?

Comment: Why not check the actual android documentation instead of blogs?
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html
and https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Comment: Because even after checking the documentation it will not work. I'm having the same problem after reading the docs. Debugger will not stop on breakpoints in C code. I've tried adding the symbols directory [which the docs barely mention without any explanation], but even after running compileDebugNdk gradle target I only get `build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release` directory and no `debug` symbols are created. EDIT: actually adding the release directory helped ;)